# Generate Custom JSON Schema using Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.Generation

Tags: c#, .net-core, json.net, jsonschema

We are using Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.Generation (C#, dotNet 5.0) and I would like generate a custom JSON schema based on the properties and its attributes of a class which has category attribute set. How do I achieve this?

Example:

```
class School
{
    [JsonProperty("Student Name", Required = Required.AllowNull)]
    [Editable(false)]
    [Category("Student")]
    [ReadOnly(true)]
    public string StudentName { get; set; }

    [Editable(true)]
    [Range(0, 1000, ErrorMessage = "Value for {0} must be between {1} and {2}.")]
    [Category("Student")]
    public int Id { get; set; } = 10;

    [JsonProperty("Parent Name", Required = Required.AllowNull)]
    [Editable(false)]
    [Category("Student")]
    public string ParentName { get; set; }


    [JsonProperty("ParentPhone", Required = Required.Default)]
    [Category("Student")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [Editable(true)]
    [Category("Staff")]
    public string TeacherName { get; set; }

    [Editable(true)]
    [Range(0, 10000, ErrorMessage = "Value for {0} must be between {1} and {2}.")]
    [DefaultValue(5000)]
    [Category("Staff")]
    public int Salary { get; set; }

    [ReadOnly(true)]
    [Category("Student")]
    public bool AvailingTransport { get; set; } = true;

    [ReadOnly(true)]
    [Category("Common")]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [ReadOnly(true)]
    [Category("Common")]
    public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
}
```

From the class above, I get a schema like:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "properties": {
    "Student Name": {
      "type": [
        "string",
        "null"
      ]
    },
    "Id": {
      "type": "integer",
      "minimum": 0.0,
      "maximum": 1000.0
    },
    "Parent Name": {
      "type": [
        "string",
        "null"
      ]
    },
    "ParentPhone": {
      "type": [
        "string",
        "null"
      ]
    },
    "TeacherName": {
      "type": [
        "string",
        "null"
      ]
    },
    "Salary": {
      "type": "integer",
      "default": 5000,
      "minimum": 0.0,
      "maximum": 10000.0
    },
    "AvailingTransport": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "Address": {
      "type": [
        "string",
        "null"
      ]
    },
    "MobileNumber": {
      "type": [
        "string",
        "null"
      ]
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "Student Name",
    "Id",
    "Parent Name",
    "TeacherName",
    "Salary",
    "AvailingTransport",
    "Address",
    "MobileNumber"
  ]
}
```

But, I would like to generate JSON schema as below:

```
{
   "type":"object",
   "additionalProperties":false,
   "properties":{
      "Address":{
         "type":[
            "string",
            "null"
         ]
      },
      "MobileNumber":{
         "type":[
            "string",
            "null"
         ]
      },
      "Student":{
         "Student Name":{
            "type":[
               "string",
               "null"
            ]
         },
         "Id":{
            "type":"integer",
            "minimum":0.0,
            "maximum":1000.0
         },
         "Parent Name":{
            "type":[
               "string",
               "null"
            ]
         },
         "ParentPhone":{
            "type":[
               "string",
               "null"
            ]
         },
         "AvailingTransport":{
            "type":"boolean"
         },
         "required":[
            "Student Name",
            "Id",
            "Parent Name",
            "AvailingTransport"
         ]
      },
      "Staff":{
         "TeacherName":{
            "type":[
               "string",
               "null"
            ]
         },
         "Salary":{
            "type":"integer",
            "default":5000,
            "minimum":0.0,
            "maximum":10000.0
         },
         "required":[
            "TeacherName",
            "Salary"
         ]
      }
   },
   "required":[
      "Address",
      "MobileNumber"
   ]
}
```

JSON Data as below:

```
{
  "Address": "XYZ",
  "MobileNumber": "1122334455",
  "Student":{
    "Student Name": "ABC",
    "Id":1,
    "Parent Name": "ABC",
    "AvailingTransport":false
  },
  "Staff":{
    "TeacherName": "ABC",
    "Salary":5000
  }
}
```

Comment: Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78185143/878701
The problem isn't the library you're using; it's that your desired schema structure doesn't match your c# type structure.  I mentioned this in the other question _and_ in the issue you opened on my github repo.

Comment: @dbc and gregsdennis: Thanks and Apologies. The problem is that the Model / class is a legacy one and it is already used by UI and other modules. If I now try to break the Model as per the Schema requirement, then the other teams shall not accept this solution or may need more changes rather than expected. 

This Model under consideration is having many properties which are grouped like "Student" and "Staff" and others falls under main object. So, I though we can group them and then create sub-objects under the main object.

I have corrected the schema above and provided the JSON data.

Comment: @dbc: Please find the validated Schema and data at https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/BVHn0SG7.

Comment: The schema and JSON do not correspond to your `School` model.  Rather than trying to restructure them on the fly during serialization, deserialization, schema generation and schema validation, you should serialize and deserialize a [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) then map that you your final model with e.g. [tag:automapper].  If you use a DTO serialization, deserialization, schema generation and schema validation will all work correctly.